# Executing batch file on remote system using Java

Tags: java, windows

How to execute a batch file located on Windows remote system? Batch file should run on remote system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abhinav,
        For your problem I see RMI is the quickest possible solution

1. Check out the basics from these links ([1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/hello/hello-world.html),[2](http://www.onezerozeroone.eu/html/rmi_howto.html))
2. Start the server from where you want to run the batch
3. In the Remote object on the server side Use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to run your batch.
4. From the client machine give call to this remote object and method.

Comment: I know this server method and also used this before but i want to do this without server

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use SSH like sshj. This only requires the remote system to have SSH installed and is more secure than RMI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) and [Expect4j](https://github.com/cverges/expect4j) for executing commands on remote machine(window/Linux). Further more, if your system allows, transfer the batch file on remote machine using some FTP utility like [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) and then execute commands that executes the script.